# Output features of a file based on its longest line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a program file_stats.py that when run on the command line, accepts a text file name as an argument and outputs the number of characters, words, lines, and the length (in characters) of the longest line in the file. Does anyone know the proper syntax to do something like this if I want the output to look like this:

```
Characters: 553
Words: 81
Lines: 21
Longest line: 38
```

Comment: Are you just looking for how to find the longest line, or all of those values?

Comment: An explainer on how to find the values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file path is a string, something like this should work

```
file = "pathtofile.txt"

with open(file, "r") as f:
    text = f.read()
    lines = text.split("\n")
    longest_line = 0
    for l in lines:
        if len(l) > longest_line:
            longest_line = len(l)
print("Longest line: {}".format(longest_line))
```

Comment: To print in the format I had above, how would I do so?

Comment: @user10200421 I won't write all the code for you, but I can help you. The other three are a lot easier. I've split the text into lines, so you can count `len(lines)` for the number of lines. For words and characters you need to do another for loop. Loop through each line and `.split(" ")` to divide by spaces. Add the length of each list together for total words. Same thing for letters but you can do `len(word)` and add those up.

Answer (score 0):

The whole program

```
n_chars = 0
n_words = 0
n_lines = 0
longest_line = 0

with open('my_text_file') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    # Find the number of Lines
    n_lines = len(lines)
    # Find the Longest line
    longest_line = max([len(line) for line in lines])
    # Find the number of Words
    words = []
    line_words = [line.split() for line in lines]
    for line in line_words:
        for word in line:
            words.append(word)
    n_words = len(words)
    # Find the number of Characters
    chars = []
    line_chars = [list(word) for word in words]
    for line in line_chars:
        for char in line:
            chars.append(char)
    n_chars = len(chars)

print("Characters: ", n_chars)
print("Words: ", n_words)
print("Lines: ", n_lines)
print("Longest: ", longest_line)
```